# In Hive query status return OK but no records are shown.

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

select *from mca_info;
OK
Time taken: 0.934 seconds

The above statement is shown.
But earlier that query worked.

Answer (score 0):

Oh ......
I Find it.
Actually data loading from HDFS file was not successful.
Actually table was empty.
When manually I inserted data in mca_info by using query "insert into table....", and then "select *from mca_info" works.
Then the data was shown.